# IoctlGetWinsize returns zero for width and height in a docker TTY container

Tags: docker, terminal, size, tty, ioctl

I'm running a docker container interactively, the instance is by all accounts a TTY, yet I cannot seem to get terminal dimensions using an ioctl (specifically calling golang's IoctlGetWinsize from golang.org/x/sys/unix/ioctl.go).

Some details, relevant container options are (for container.Config):

```
            AttachStdin:  true,
            AttachStdout: true,
            AttachStderr: true,
            OpenStdin:    true,
            Tty:          true,
            StdinOnce:    true,
```

and when invoking ContainerAttach:

```
    resp, err := cli.ContainerAttach(noCtx, containerName, types.ContainerAttachOptions{
        Stream: true,
        Stdin:  true,
        Stdout: true,
        Stderr: true,
    })
```

and then forwarding i/o

```
    go io.Copy(os.Stderr, resp.Reader)
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Reader)
    go io.Copy(resp.Conn, os.Stdin)

    fd := int(os.Stdin.Fd())
    var oldState *terminal.State
    if terminal.IsTerminal(fd) {
        oldState, err = terminal.MakeRaw(fd)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Unable to make raw terminal\n%w", err)
        }
        defer terminal.Restore(fd, oldState)
    }
```

the code in question, when run outside of docker retrieves the terminal size without issue, but within docker the call succeeds without error but responds as though not a TTY with 0 dimensions.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Expected to get the terminal size.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be simpler than I thought.  The process managing the container needs to forward size information to the container from the host, including resize events.  Seems somewhat obvious now, but took a bit to figure it out.